# How to scrape the content without entire cookies details / How to bypass that?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using selenium `beautifulsoup` to scrape the content from Indeed , however i am also getting the entire cookies details. How to skip cookies info and only get's the content what shows on page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager



url = 'https://uk.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=b4fea8232173a7ae&tk=1gf89ph6gg3mi801&from=mobhp_jobfeed'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get(url)

raw_text = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml",).get_text(strip=True, separator=". ")
print(raw_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Question needs some improvment to clarify - Assuming that you only want specific information, try to select you elements more specific:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
soup.select_one('.jobsearch-JobComponent').get_text('.',strip=True)
```

Alternative to get rid of cookie banner information, simply click it:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#onetrust-reject-all-handler').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```